# remove duplicate and replace it with empty space

Tags: awk, sed, uniq

I have a table as of below

```
fruits   shopname 
Apple     x1
orange    x1
banana    x2
Apple     x3
orange    x2
banana    x3
```

I want to group all rows based on column 1 and replace the duplicates with empty space.

It will look like below.

```
fruits   shopname 
Apple     x1
          x3
banana    x2
          x3
orange    x1
          x2
```

I know we can remove duplicates with `uniq` command.
but here I want to group them and replace duplicates with empty space.

Comment: Hello Anthony. This looks like coursework, so what have you tried so far?

Comment: You can't group by column 1 - it contains only unique values 1 to 6.

Comment: According to your text column `fruits` seems to be the real column 1. Adding line numbers is confusing. I suggest to remove the line number column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file line by line, and build up a data structure that associates the fruit to a *list* of shop numbers. You can do this with awk's multidimensional arrays, or with GNU awk's array of arrays.

Then, after you have read the file, you will loop over the fruits, and for each fruit, print out a line for each shop.

I'd use perl for this, but the syntax for perl can be somewhat overwhelming.

```
perl -lane '
    if ($. == 1) {print; next}
    push @{$shops{$F[0]}}, $F[1];
  }END{
    for $fruit (sort {lc $a cmp lc $b} keys %shops) {
        $label = $fruit;
        for $shop (@{$shops{$fruit}}) {
            printf "%s\t%s\n", $label, $shop;
            $label = "";
       }
    }
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sort -t $'\t' <(tail -n+2 infile) |awk 'seen[$1]++{ $1="" }1' OFS='\t'
Apple   x1
        x3
banana  x2
        x3
orange  x1
        x2
```

I don't understand why do you need empty fruits name, which you can simply query the data you need, everything other than result you can consider it's empty.

```
sort -t $'\t' -uk1,1 <(tail -n+2 infile)
Apple   x1
banana  x2
orange  x1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used below method to achieve the same

```
for i in `awk '{print $1}' y.txt| sort| uniq| tr "\n" " "`; do awk -v i="$i" '$1 == i {print  $2}' y.txt| sed "1s/.*/$i\t&/g"| sed '/^x/s/.*/\t&/g';done| sed '1i fruits   shopname '
```

output

```
fruits   shopname 
Apple   x1
        x3
banana  x2
        x3
orange  x1
        x2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version using sed, but the first that creates an input file.

Make sure you disable your bash history expansion with `set +H` before running this

**Code:** (copy & paste into your shell)

```
# replace comma with tab to enable copy&paste from stackexchange,
# sort the table, write the file
cat <<EOF | tr ";" "\t" |sort > fruits.txt
Apple;x1
orange;x1
banana;x2
Apple;x3
orange;x2
banana;x3
EOF

echo "BEFORE:"
cat fruits.txt

for fruit in $(cut -f1 fruits.txt|sort -u); do sed -i "/$fruit/!b;n;s/^\w\+//" fruits.txt; done

echo "RESULT:"
cat fruits.txt
```

**Output:**

```
BEFORE:
Apple   x1
Apple   x3
banana  x2
banana  x3
orange  x1
orange  x2
RESULT:
Apple   x1
        x3
banana  x2
        x3
orange  x1
        x2
```